# Play phone game with game being displayed on computer screen

Tags: applications, remote-access

I want to play InfiniteFlight on my computer. But it's only available for phones (and maybe tablets, I'm not sure) - I purchased InfiniteFlight on my phone, and I just had an idea -

What if we can make the game *appear* on the computer screen via wifi and some app? Can we do this? how can we do this?

Comment: Oh, and I'm on Linux now so any software would need to be compatible with Linux (Ubuntu)

Comment: It's called *screen mirroring*, and included with the latest CyanogenMod if I heard right. Knowing the term, you can try [a search for it on ASE](http://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=screen+mirror). 17 hits to check; please update your question with your results (so we see what you've already tried and why it didn't work, and know where to start), or even answer it if they could solve your issue. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you @Izzy, it definitely helps a lot when you know the correct terms to use when searching. I'll post my solution or update my question when I'd checked it out.